# open shared folder from web application

Tags: html, perl, cross-browser, cgi

I have one in house Perl web application (Windows OS), and I need to find the best way to open shared folder from my application with user default file explorer. I prefer some Perl module or some cross browser method (I don't know what browser would be used by user).

I tried with `file:///` but I am searching for something better.

Comment: How do you define "shared folder"? What OSes and file managers are you targeting? Remember that Firefox disallows following `file://`-URLs from documents served with HTTP. (Anonymous) FTP may be the most portable solution, but is very restricted. It would also be good to understand your *intent* in opening a shared resource.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is something like accessing a file on a samba share, I would suggest simply using UNC paths (\yourserver\shared_folder\filename). If you point to an actual file it will be opened by the default program associated with that extension in Windows. If you point to a folder, the windows explorer would open up in that folder, as if you typed the UNC path in a start -> run dialog box.

So in perl this would be like below, if your shared folder is on server named "phobos" with a share "movies".

```
system('\\phobos\movies'); # mind the quoting!!
```

If you were trying to open up a file in the default program in windows you would use something like:

```
system('\\phobos\movies\my_cool_movie.avi'); # mind the quoting!!
```

Is that what you mean with your question?

Comment: Even with single quoting, there are escape codes: \\ → \. Therefore, backslashes are the way of the devil, and even Windows understands forward slashes.

Comment: @amon, true, but that is besides the question. This user is clearly on Windows and confusing him with both forward slashes or doubled up slashes seemed a bit overkill. I simply wanted to point out that a simple system call with the path he likes to access should work on windows. He probqbly won't be using hardcoded paths anyway and would  most likely need double quotes anyway to interpolate the vars he uses.
`system("\\\\phobos\\movies");` should do the trick.

Comment: BTW, forward slashes only work when the resource is to be access from the browser. Windows thinks you mean `http://` when you pass it ` \\ `.
For example `\\wdtvlive` works for me, but `//wdtvlive` opens up a browser and shows an error page.